# FFMPEG returns negative values and stops rendering

Tags: ffmpeg

While trying to get a 16:9 aspect output from any resolution input, I keep running into errors.

This is, what I prompt:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -i "overlay.png" -strict -2 -vcodec h264 -aspect 16:9 -filter_complex "[0]scale=604:-2,pad=604:340:(604-iw)/2:(340-ih)/2[v];[v][1]overlay=x=W-w-5:y=H-h-5" -an "output.mp4"
```

Errors are:

```
[0] => [Parsed_pad_1 @ 0xeffca0] Negative values are not acceptable.
[1] => [Parsed_pad_1 @ 0xeffca0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_1
[2] => Error configuring complex filters.
[3] => Invalid argument
```

I'm happy for any help.

Comment: 602-iw. If input width is greater than 604, this subtraction will produce a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

If your input dimensions are larger than the pad target, then filter setup will fail. The error message should be improved.

As a workaround, use

```
pad=604:max(340\,ih):-1:-1
```

The `-1` tells the filter to centre the input in the padded frame along that dimension.

Comment: Hm that didn't really work. I used:


`ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -i "clip_overlay.png" -vcodec h264 -aspect 16:9 -filter_complex "[0]scale=604:-2,pad=604:max(340\,ih):-1:-1[v];[v][1]overlay=x=W-w-5:y=H-h-5" -an "out.mp4"`

and still got the error :/.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: ...server does not have log-permission "Failed to open report "ffmpeg-20200115-150607.log": Permission denied".

Comment: Add -v 48 and redirect stderr to a writeable location.